# Changing only the size of a UIFont on a UIButton

Tags: iphone, ipad

What is the fastest/simplest way to change only the size of the existing font on a UIButton?  (pointSize is read-only)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 74):

```
UILabel* titleLabel = button.titleLabel;
titleLabel.font = [titleLabel.font fontWithSize:12345];
```